# Print String with repeated characters

Tags: java

```
public class Envelope{
    public static int width = 80;
    public static int height = 10;
    public static int distance = 40;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for(int i =0; i < 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("+");

            for(int b = 2; b<=width;b++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            for(int d =1; d<=1;d++) {
                System.out.println("+");

                for(int e=1; e<height; e++) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
            }
        }
            for(int a=1; a<height; a++) {
                System.out.println("|");
            }
                for(int c = 11; c < 12; c++) {
                    System.out.print("+");
                    for(int f = 0; f<width;f++) {
                        System.out.print("-");
                    }
                        for(int g=1;g<=1;g++) {
                            System.out.print("+");
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

My current output is too long so instead of `println()` I used `print()` just to show my current output.

```java
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|||||||||+
```

So my problem is how can I put this symbol "-" after the plus symbol but this "-" must go 80 times to the right side.

```
I want to do this...as an example

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Try `String.repeat("-",width)`

Comment: Edit the question to show the current output and the desired output

Comment: I just added the current output of the program and as he mentioned that his expected output. @tkruse

Comment: _Try `String.repeat("-",width)` – PatrickChen_                                                                    As I mentioned in my answer `repeat()` is available for **Java >= 11**

Comment: i will edit my code so you can show where i stuck.

Comment: Please insert your expected output then Everybody can help. I personally don't understand what you want as output.

Comment: I will do now under my code.

Comment: @anfaenger_tester Kindly check my updated answer hope now you'll get how to format string. Let me know if it is working for you.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
System.out.println("-".repeat(80));
```

Comment: Java doesn't have a repeat method

Comment: *Java doesn't have a repeat method – MCMastery* http://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/…

Comment: Java has `repeat()`. In Java 11 It introduced [repeat()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that. I'd un-downvote  and upvote this but it isn't letting me...

Comment: @MCMastery  Not a big deal.  Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

As @WJS mentioned in his answer it is useful if you are using **Java 11**. Here I mentioned another way by which you are able to do with **Java <= 11**.

```java
    System.out.println("+");
    // For **Java <= 7**
    System.out.println(String.format("%0" + 80 + "d", 0).replace("0", "-"));
    // For **Java >= 8**
    System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(10, "|")));
    System.out.println("+");
```

> **Note:** You can format this as you want.

**Updated Answer**
As you mentioned your expected output I did that. Also, you can do this by using anything but for your understanding, I used an easy solution.

```java
        System.out.print("+");
        System.out.print(String.format("%0" + 80 + "d", 0).replace("0", "-"));
        System.out.print("+");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s", "|");
            System.out.printf("%81s", "|");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print("+");
        System.out.print(String.format("%0" + 80 + "d", 0).replace("0", "-"));
        System.out.print("+");
```

> Let me know If it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("-".repeat(80));
        for(int i =0; i < 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("+");
            for(int b =0; b<i;b++) {
                System.out.println("-".repeat(80));
            }
        }
```

I want that this symbol "-" is on the line with "+" and in the of this "-" it comes a "+" again :) so the first problem is how can i take this "-" next to "+"